# Snap CLion IDE exits on run

Tags: snap, c++, c, 22.10, clion

I installed snap package of CLion IDE, when I launch it from ULauncher it exits upon clicking run, however when I run it from the terminal it seems to work just fine, what could be the cause of this?

Using Ubuntu 22.10. (The same happens with WebStorm, however I've been using IntelliJ Ultimate and it works great, all of them are snap packages)

Comment: Can you launch the app from Gnome, without ULauncher?

Comment: Yes, I launch and run the programs just fine, hmm. I should perhaps clarify that the IDE itself launches no matter the method, it just seems to crash when I run a program (SHIFT + F10) through ULauncher

Comment: @ararune Did you find a solution to this problem?